# Why does C# truncate string precision during Format?

Tags: c#, format, string-formatting, precision

Given a string and a double of equal value, string.Format truncates differently.

```
double x = 88.2;
string y = "88.2";
string output_1 = String.Format("{0:0.00}", x);
string output_2 = String.Format("{0:0.00}", y);
```

In this instance, output_1 will be '88.20' and output_2 is '88.2'.

Is there a way to do this without using

```
Double double_var;
string output;
if (Double.TryParse(input, out double_var))
{
    output = String.Format("{0:0.00}", double_var);
}
else
{
    output = String.Format("{0:0.00}", input);
}
```

This is for a generic file builder I'm creating for recordsets to files and I would really like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: "0.00" does not apply to a string variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String.Format won't apply a format to a string. You know that the string contains a number, but .NET doesn't.

So yes, you'll have to parse the string to a number and format that number.

From [MSDN: String.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A number of types support format strings, including all numeric types (both standard and custom format strings), all dates and times (both standard and custom format strings) and time intervals (both standard and custom format strings), all enumeration types enumeration types, and GUIDs. You can also add support for format strings to your own types.

This does not include strings.

In order for an object to support custom format strings, it needs to [implement `IFormattable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable(v=vs.110).aspx), which the types mentioned above do.

Given these classes:

```
public class FormattableFoo : IFormattable 
{
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return $"FooFormat: '{format}'";
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

And these calls:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", new Foo());
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", new FormattableFoo());
```

The output will be:

```
Foo
FooFormat: '0.00'
```

Given [`System.String` doesn't implement `IFormattable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) (and neither does `Foo`), its `ToString()` method will be called without a format.

See also [MSDN: Customizing Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/0asazeez(v=vs.71)).

Comment: Likewise, from `String`'s `.ToString`: "no actual conversion is performed."

Answer (score 0):

`string` does not implement `IFormattable` so any specified formatting argument will be just ignored. On the other hand, `double` can interpret the provided `0.00` format specifier.

Side note: C# 6 has a `FormattableString` but just for supporting different cultures for the format arguments in interpolated strings.